# Can't copy files to a folder

Tags: android, file, copy, storage

**Task:** I want to copy selected files from `A` folder to `B` folder. Both folders are in the external storage.

**Problem**: It works perfectly fine, however, at some point it just stops copying files. For example, if I want to copy 500 files, it would copy only 110 files. Also I've noticed that I can't copy video files, it works only with images.

**Code**:

The method which I use to copy files:

```
  private static void makeFileCopy(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(source);
        os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    }finally {
        try {
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
            if (os != null)
                os.close();
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

One more:

```
 public static void copyFileList(Context context, List<MediaFile> contentList, File mediaFolder) {
    if (contentList != null) {
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        for (int index=0;index<contentList.size();index++) {
            MediaFile mediaFile=contentList.get(index);
            File file = new File(mediaFolder, mediaFile.mediaFile().getName());
            boolean isVideo=mediaFile.getType()== MediaFile.Type.VIDEO;
            if (!file.exists()) {
                try {
                    if (!file.createNewFile()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    FileUtils.makeFileCopy(mediaFile.getRealFile().getAbsoluteFile(), file);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }

                if (isVideo) {
                    values.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
                    context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                } else {
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
                    context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                }
                values.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does it always copy the 110 files only? Regarding the video files - how big are they? If you put a small video file, is it also ignored? Did you check the log for any exceptions?

Comment: `if (!file.createNewFile()) {
                        continue;`. Remove that cods. It's useless.

Comment: Try without the ContentValues stuff for a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've solved that problem. This is extremely stupid mistake I've made.

**Solution:** I wanted to make a copy of files which I already had in my destination folder, and by checking `if (!file.exists())` it just did not pass. So, I've come up with the following code:

```
public static void copyFileList(Context context, List<MediaFile> contentList, File mediaFolder) {
    if (contentList != null) {
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        for (int index=0;index<contentList.size();index++) {
            MediaFile mediaFile=contentList.get(index);
            String fileName=mediaFile.mediaFile().getName();

            boolean isVideo=mediaFile.getType()== MediaFile.Type.VIDEO;
            File file = new File(mediaFolder, fileName);
            //let a user to decide whether to create a copy of already existing files
            if(!file.exists()) {
                file=new File(mediaFolder,uniqueNameFor(fileName));
            }

            if(!file.exists()) {
                try {
                    FileUtils.makeFileCopy(mediaFile.mediaFile().getAbsoluteFile(), file);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }

                if (isVideo) {
                    values.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
                    values.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.MIME_TYPE,mediaFile.getMimeType());
                    context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                } else {
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE,mediaFile.getMimeType());
                    context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                }

            }
            values.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Just create a unique name of the file.

Also I did change the copy method:

```
   private static void makeFileCopy(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    FileChannel inputChannel = null;
    FileChannel outputChannel = null;
    try {
        inputChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
        outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
        outputChannel.transferFrom(inputChannel, 0, inputChannel.size());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (inputChannel != null)
                inputChannel.close();
            if (outputChannel != null)
                outputChannel.close();
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Using channels is a little bit faster than using previous approach.
Check out 4 ways how to copy files [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/file/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java/).

Thank you for help!